# How to get history of Pods run on Kubernetes Node?

Tags: java, linux, linux-kernel, kubernetes

In our Kuberenetes cluster, we are running into sporadic situations where a cluster node runs out of memory and Linux invokes OOM killer. Looking at the logs, it appears that the Pods scheduled onto the Node are requesting more memory than can be allocated by the Node.

The issue is that, when OOM killer is invoked, it prints out a list of processes and their memory usage. However, as all of our Docker containers are Java services, the "process name" just appears as "java", not allowing us to track down which particular Pod is causing the issues.

How can I get the history of which Pods were scheduled to run on a particular Node and when?

Comment: One way would be to check `kubectl get events` and get an idea of creation/deletion of various pods on different nodes.

Comment: If the pods on a node have consumed all the memory of said node then this should not trigger the OOM killer. What it should trigger is (1) Kubernetes migrating one or more pods to a different node (for your application that should mean it receives a SIGTERM) in order free up memory, and then allowing the remaining pods to consume the just freed memory.
The OOM killer should only be invoked when a pod tries to consume more memory that its configured `limit`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) to monitor OOM events.

This expression should report the number of times that memory usage has reached the limits:

```
rate(container_memory_failcnt{pod_name!=""}[5m]) > 0
```

FYI: this is the next best thing to proper docs, [the code](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/master/metrics/prometheus.go#L221)

Comment: @camil's answer below is using a better metric source: kube_pod_container_status_terminated_reason

Answer (score 10):

You can now use kube-state-metrics `kube_pod_container_status_terminated_reason` to detect OOM events

```
kube_pod_container_status_terminated_reason{reason="OOMKilled"}

kube_pod_container_status_terminated_reason{container="addon-resizer",endpoint="http-metrics",instance="100.125.128.3:8080",job="kube-state-metrics",namespace="monitoring",pod="kube-state-metrics-569ffcff95-t929d",reason="OOMKilled",service="kube-state-metrics"}
```

Answer (score 3):

Event history for your particular namespace, ordered by creationTimestamp:

```
kubectl get events -n YOURNAMESPACE -o wide --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp
```

Or if you want to check the event history for all namespaces, ordered by creationTimestamp:

```
kubectl get events --all-namespaces -o wide --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your pods don't have [requests and limits](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/) set, or the values are not ideal.

If you setup this properly, when a pod starts to use too much ram, that pod will be killed and you will be able to find out what is causing the issues.

About seeing all the pods on a node, you can go with `kubectl get events` or `docker ps -a` on the node, as cited on the other answers/comments.

Answer (score -4):

One way is to see `docker ps -a` output and correlate the container names with your pod's containers.